# Issue in my Drupal site

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, helper

I am unable to login admin panel of my site which is developed in Drupal. I had tried the below link, but it's showing as "You are not authorized to login this page"

> http://fujisushiflorida.com/?q=admin

After some surfing in net I had tried the below link. It had shown the login page, but the password I had entered is not correct think. So I had planned to change the password in DB. I had gone to phpmyadmin in that selected "user" table and the first reflecting data is the admin data so I had changed the password of that directly in DB also changed the function to MD5 since pwd has been encrypted. Post changing the password I tried to login but getting the error as "unrecognized username and password"

> http://fujisushiflorida.com/user

Can you please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly user info is stored, but generally speaking you can install new Drupal site, grab table rows of your admin account there and move them to problematic site, where you lost your account.

Comment: currently my site Drupal version is 7.9... Do you need me to upgrade the site.

I cant able to find any seperate table for admin in mysql

Answer (score 0):

In the database check that you have a user with id of 1 and check that their username and email are what you are expecting.

To reset the password:

If your site is sending emails you should just be able to request a new password.

If you can create an anonymous user without admin verification create one with a password. then in the database copy the password from the new user to the number 1 user.

Otherwise create a user on a clean install or dev site and copy over the password from the database.

Comment: if you copy the following into the password field that will set the password to password $S$D08dJC8VC3FFz7GgOprO67ZGE89jY5Mpv.BZy/v9tjZZg4JMVpFX then you can update it to something more secure when logged in.

Comment: you mean i need to update the below as password in user table

$S$D08dJC8VC3FFz7GgOprO67ZGE89jY5Mpv.BZy/v9tjZZg4JMVpFX

Comment: Yes if you put this in the password column of the user table for the user that you are trying to log in as it will set their password to password

Answer (score 0):

Try the forgot password on the login screen if your admin has your email address.

If you can SSH into the server your site is hosted on, install drush if you do not have it and use the drush user-login